# I cannot open Gnome Tweak Tool on gnome ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, themes, gnome

I cannot open Gnome Tweak Tool on gnome ubuntu 12.04

I want to install gnome themes,but I've got a problem is Gnome Tweak Tool cannot open

so how do i change themes on gnome.

I had already install Faience icon theme and Holo themes on my ubuntu.

Can someone teach me how to change to this themes,thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open HUD and find Advance setting - For gnome tweak tool.

Did you place your theme and icon on correct place?

This is manual step to change icon and theme using terminal on ubuntu.

**Change Icon**

Enable the default Faience icon theme with this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Faience'
```

For Faience-Azur:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Faience-Azur'
```

For Faience-Ocre:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Faience-Ocre'
```

For Faience-Claire:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Faience-Claire'
```

**Change Theme**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Holo'

gconftool-2 --set --type string /apps/metacity/general/theme 'Holo'
```

**#Replace holo-theme with your Folder theme name**

http://penreturns.rc.my/2012/02/how-to-install-and-enable-faience-icon.html

Comment: Thank you I can change icon on my ubuntu now but I still cannot change my theme on my ubuntu and I had already install Advance setting but just not response.

Comment: can i get URL where you download the theme?

Comment: ok http://tiheum.deviantart.com/art/Holo-280076980? Thank you so much!

Comment: ok now replace the 'holo-theme' with 'Holo'

Comment: The problem have been solve,thank you for you helping.

Comment: no problem sir.. enjoy ubuntu!